# Getting error while Winsorizing in Python

Tags: python, data-cleaning, outliers

I am trying to winsorize the columns of my pandas dataframe using.

```
data=[[1,267],[2,678],[3,50000000000],[4,546],[5,1],[6,567],[7,674],[8,.],[9,65],[10,.]]
```

df_temp=pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['customer_id', 'Revenue'])

#Let's suppose that data type of the varaible Revenue is object where the missing values are recorded as type None as That is the case with the variables I am working with. This is a reproducible example

#Converting the None Missing values to NaN
df_temp['Revenue'].replace([None], np.nan, inplace=True)

#Converting the object data type to numeric
df_temp['Revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df_temp['Revenue'])

#Imputing the missing values with Median
df_temp['Revenue'].fillna(value=df_temp['Revenue'].median(),inplace=True)
Don't know if that aspect of this variable can be related to this error

#Winsorizing
df_temp['Revenue'] = scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize(df_temp['Revenue'], limits =[0.01,0.01] , inplace=True)

If I remove the variables having object data type from my data frame, then the code is working fine.

I am getting the following error.

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

To the best of my knowledge my syntax is correct and I do not have any `NaN` values or missing values in my data. Any help that I can get to solve this error will be very helpful.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you post a [mre] and the full details of the exception.

Comment: what is `df_temp['sum_gmv']` and are you using [this_winsorizing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html)

Comment: I have added a reproducible example in the original code by editing it. I think it is related to the fact that the data type of the variable in my data set is object. I converted it to a numeric integer and imputed the missing values with median.  If I remove the variables having object data type, the code works fine.

Comment: Yes, I am using scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize